# How to find the mean of a continuous variable for each categorical variable?

Tags: r, mean, categorical-data, continuous, na.rm

I am trying to calculate the average duration of UFO sighting (continuous) for each categorical shape that it is related with.  Essentially, what is the average sighting length for each UFO shape?

I tried:

```
    a <- aggregate(duration..seconds. ~ shape, data=alien, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
    barplot(a$duration..seconds., names.arg=a$shape)
```

and got:

```
    no non-missing arguments to min; returning Infno non-missing arguments to max; 
    returning -InfError in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) : need finite 'ylim' values
```

I realize that I need to alter my data somehow. I would like to simply remove all of the data that has missing corresponding data (ie, we know the shape but the duration is missing - and vice versa), but I don't quite know how to do this.

Thanks for your help!

PS. the "duration..seconds." is correct, that is how it transferred over from the excel file.

```
    shape       duration..seconds.
    us  changing    3600    NA  4/27/2004   29.8830556  
    us  changing    300     NA  12/16/2005  29.38421    
    us  changing    3600    NA  1/21/2008   53.2    
    us  changing    900     NA  1/17/2004   28.9783333  
    ca  changing    1200    NA  1/22/2004   21.4180556  
    us  changing    3600    NA  4/27/2007   36.595
```

There are 80000 logs of UFO sightings, which is why I am trying to average it. And there are 29 different shapes.

Comment: Soooo....do we get to see some sample data?

Comment: Duplicate was was the first hit for search on "[r] mean each categorical variable". Learn to search before posting. Downvote for "lack of effort".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data

```
df <- read.table(text="
country shape  duration_seconds dummy1 date dummy2
us  changing    3600    NA  4/27/2004   29.8830556  
us  changing    300     NA  12/16/2005  29.38421    
us  changing    3600    NA  1/21/2008   53.2    
us  changing    900     NA  1/17/2004   28.9783333  
ca  changing    1200    NA  1/22/2004   21.4180556  
us  changing    3600    NA  4/27/2007   36.595  
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You can fix the column titles with

```
names(df) <- c("country", "shape", "duration_seconds", "dummy1", "date", "dummy2")
```

Using library dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(shape)  %>%
  summarize(mean_duration_seconds = mean(duration_seconds))

#   shape    mean_duration_seconds
#   <chr>                    <dbl>
# 1 changing                 2200.
```

And using the original code

```
names(df) <- c("country", "shape", "duration_seconds", "dummy1", "date", "dummy2")
a <- aggregate(duration_seconds ~ shape, data=df, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
barplot(a$duration_seconds, names.arg=a$shape)

a
#   shape    duration_seconds
# 1 changing             2200
```